# Linux replace only user part in email pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have users like below in many *sh scripts.

```
test1@gmail.com
user@ymail.com
test2@gmail.com
```

I want to replace any emails like above with **admin@yahoo.com** in linux.

Any idea will be appreciated ?

Answer (score 3):

To replace the part before `@` (I think that's what you want), you could use:

```
sed 's/[^ ]\+@/admin@/g' file
```

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `[^ ]\+@` match at least one non-whitespace character followed by `@`
- `g` do the replacement on all matches, even if it occurs more than once on the line.